# Assert text for partial text match

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to write a Selenium test to validate some text in the form "Found X results in Y seconds", where Y changes. I understand Selenium doesn't support wildcards, but does support XPath expressions. But my test is always failing.

Element:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 apex-col-auto" >
        <div id="R97298480703869613"  class=""> 
            Found            0 results in        0.138 seconds.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Value:

```
xpath=(//div[contains(text(), "Found")])
```

Test:

[image]

But I'm only getting results like:

```
Failed: Actual value "Found 0 results in 0.007 seconds." 
did not match "xpath=(//div[contains(text(), "Found")])"
```

I've tried `text()`, `./text()`, and just `.` Am I just writing this XPath expression incorrectly?

Comment: Try using `xpath='//div[contains(text(), "Found")]'` instead and see if it works.

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: Works for me when I try it. There may be something unusual in your html. It may help if you edit your question and add some more of the context where that `div` is located.

Comment: I've added more context to the `div` above and some more details, but there's just not much more else to add.

Comment: Your xpath expressions are fine; the only thing I can think of is that the html is malformed and contains another element with the same `id` attribute value....

Comment: No, did a search on the whole document source and that's the only instance of that string.

Answer (score 2):

```
store text|[your element]|StoredText
execute script|return ${StoredText}.includes("Found")|x
assert|x|true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 